# PHPExcel is appending [<=9999999] in front of large integer phone numbers

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I am using the excelToArray function found here: https://gist.github.com/calvinchoy/5821235

```
function excelToArray($filePath, $header = true) {
    require_once("./PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php"));
    //Create excel reader after determining the file type
    $inputFileName = $filePath;
    /**  Identify the type of $inputFileName  **/
    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
    /**  Create a new Reader of the type that has been identified  **/
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    /** Set read type to read cell data onl **/
    // $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true); removed because: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46142706/
    /**  Load $inputFileName to a PHPExcel Object  **/
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
    //Get worksheet and built array with first row as header
    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    //excel with first row header, use header as key
    if($header){
        $highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();
        $highestColumn = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn();
        $headingsArray = $objWorksheet->rangeToArray('A1:'.$highestColumn.'1',null, true, true, true);
        $headingsArray = $headingsArray[1];
        $r = -1;
        $namedDataArray = array();
        for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
            $dataRow = $objWorksheet->rangeToArray('A'.$row.':'.$highestColumn.$row,null, true, true, true);
            if ((isset($dataRow[$row]['A'])) && ($dataRow[$row]['A'] > '')) {
                ++$r;
                foreach($headingsArray as $columnKey => $columnHeading) {
                    $namedDataArray[$r][$columnHeading] = $dataRow[$row][$columnKey];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        //excel sheet with no header
        $namedDataArray = $objWorksheet->toArray(null,true,true,true);
    }
    return $namedDataArray;
}
```

I have a sample spreadsheet in Excel.  Here it is:

Preview: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2GilRTNrTzKRUVsQWhnQkRLUmM

Direct Download: https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B2GilRTNrTzKRUVsQWhnQkRLUmM&export=download

The problem is that when I upload the spreadsheet I'm seeing that phone numbers (which are simply large integers (ex: `2345556789`) in the spreadsheet I am provided) are coming in with `[<=9999999]` in front of them. Ex: `[<=9999999]1393153-7665`

What is causing this and how I do get it to simple read it in as an string (or even an int)?

Comment: What are the actual values stored in the cell, and the number format mask applied to that cell?

Comment: I provided a sample spreadsheet in the question (publically hosted Google Drive file).  The field contains an integer, like 12345556789, but when the cell does not have focus in Excel it looks like (234) 555-6789.

Comment: You provided view access... I can't read the format mask, or see the actual value, only see the Google formatted result.... that's insufficient to try and identify all the information that I need to identify any problem

Comment: There is a download button in the top-right which gives a link to the direct XLSX file, which is here: https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B2GilRTNrTzKRUVsQWhnQkRLUmM&export=download

Comment: @MarkBaker Any thoughts since I exposed the file better?